# JavaScript element validation

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to check if anything in my multiple dropdown list has been selected using javascript.

```
<select name="id" id="id" size=22 multiple >
```

And also if any checkboxes has been checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inst" class="asa" value="inst1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="inst" class="asa" value="inst2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/bYNsG/1/)**

```
var selectVal = document.getElementById('id');
var selectCount = 0;
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selectVal.options.length; i++) {
  if (selectVal.options[i].selected) {
    selectCount++;
    values.push(selectVal.options[i].value);
  }
}
```

for checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inst" class="asa" id="check1" value="inst1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="inst" class="asa" id="check2" value="inst2">

var check1 = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
alert(check1);
var check2 = document.getElementById("check2").checked;
alert(check2);
```

Comment: thanks! didn't knew loops would be needed

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var select = document.getElementById('id');

var selected  = [];
for(var i =0 ; i < select.options.length; i++){
    if(select.options[i].selected){
        selected.push(select.options[i].value);
    }
}
if(selected.length == 0){
    alert('not selected');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KeRLv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select name="id" id="three" size=22 multiple>
    <option value="thevalue">Option</option>
</select>

<select name="id" id="four" size=22 multiple>
    <option value="thevalue" selected="selected">Option</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var three = document.getElementById("three");

if(one.checked)
    console.log("one = checked!");
else
    console.log("one != checked");

if(two.checked)
    console.log("two = checked!");
else
    console.log("two != checked");

if(three.value)
    console.log("something is selected in three!");
else
    console.log("nothing is selected in three");

if(four.value)
    console.log("something is selected in four!");
else
    console.log("nothing is selected in four");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/P2c6e/) covering both the checkbox and select.

Obviously this is a very verbose example, but you can trim it down to take away what you need.